# Apply digitize() to ndarray by row

Tags: python, numpy, row

I have a sample ndarray with NaNs

```
import numpy as np

m,n,c  = 10,5,15;
A      = np.random.randn(m,n)
linidx = np.random.choice(A.size, c, replace=False)
np.put(A,linidx,np.nan)
```

I want to find which decile a value belongs to, and I want to do it by row.

Hence, I calculate the percentiles:

```
edges = np.nanpercentile(A,range(10,110,10),axis=1)
```

and then I need to apply the `digitize()` function on each row of `A` and using the corresponding `edge`.

I was looking at `np.apply_along_axis()` but maybe I should just explicitly loop by row?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but maybe [`2D interpolation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) could help?

Answer (score 1):

I went for now with the following solution:

```
bins = np.zeros((m,n),np.int64)
for r in range(A.shape[0]):
    bins[r,:] = np.digitize(A[r,:], edges[r,:])
```

Faster or more elegant alternatives are welcome